# How to de-acidify room where floor is bleached?

Tags: cleaning, safety, house-cleaning

Eager to get my room squeaky clean, I accidently (stupidly) sprayed bleach (the one used to whiten clothes, NaClO I think) all over the marble floor and then sprinkled water (with hand) before cleaning it all with a squeegee.

While cleaning my eyes started to burn (mild), air started to smell like acid, and I felt extra moist inside my nose. So I quickly opened all windows and doors, turned on the fan and left the room.

Now, how do I de-acidify the room? I feel strange when I enter the room right now.
Also, bleach has made the floor very very slippery, what can I do to undo this effect (preferably without water)?

---

I just noticed, standing on bleach+water mix cured my cracked heels a lot.

**Edit:** I hope this question is suitable for Lifehacks.SE, if not please migrate where appropriate

Comment: It's not acid, but alkali and Cl2, that are the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can either rinse the floor with fresh water repeatedly working in a small area at a time (until "slippery" feeling from bleach is gone) or neutralize the sodium hypochlorite in the bleach with a Hydrogen Peroxide solution.

Bleach neutralizing solution: Use 1 part Hydrogen Peroxide to 10 parts water.

You might want to wear rubber gloves for your hands and eye protection for unintentional splashes.

Good luck.

Comment: Can you please write the equation involved so others can be sure that hydrogen peroxide will really neutralize bleach

Comment: NaOCl + H202 > NaCl + H20 + 02 (numbers are subscripted)